# How can i switch to another Fragment programmatically?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment

I' ve got two Fragments (layout_first.xml and layout_second.xml).
I want to do this: click a Button (Show Second) in the first Fragment to show the second Fragment and get an EditText value in the first Fragment to set the EditText value in the second Fragment programmaticaly.

Here is my code:

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/custom_tab_layout_height"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

layout_first.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:background="#bc8383">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show Second"
        android:id="@+id/btnShowSecond"
        android:layout_weight="0.18" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et1"
        android:text="et1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:elegantTextHeight="false"
        android:maxLength="20"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#85b27e"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

layout_second.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:background="#bc8383">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et2"
        android:text="et2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:elegantTextHeight="false"
        android:maxLength="20"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#85b27e"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="btn2"
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

custom_tab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tab"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:fontFamily="@string/font_fontFamily_medium"/>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package xmaxsoft.delfragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabIcons();
    }

    private void setupTabIcons() {
        TextView tabOne = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        tabOne.setText("One");
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);

        TextView tabTwo = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        tabTwo.setText("Two");
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(tabTwo);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new First(), "One");
        adapter.addFrag(new Second(), "Two");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

First.java

```
package xmaxsoft.delfragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class First extends Fragment {
    public First() {
    }

    Button btnShowSecond;
    EditText et1;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_first, container, false);
        btnShowSecond = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnShowSecond);
        et1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et1);
        btnShowSecond.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            //what kind of code must be here ???
            //what kind of code must be here ???
            //what kind of code must be here ???
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

Second.java

```
package xmaxsoft.delfragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Second extends Fragment {
    public Second() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_second, container, false);
        //
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use code:-

```
 Fragment fragment = new XXXFragment();
       if (fragment != null) {

 FragmentManager fragmentManager   =getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment, "TAG").commit();
```

}

Comment: thank you for your answer but i can not do this. where can i use this code and what can i replace R.id.frame_container with?

Comment: you can put your code where you want to show new fragment and  this  R.id.frame_container   is a  frame layout <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/frame_container" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:clickable="true"/>

Comment: sorry i am newbie on android and so please tell me how can i adapt this code to my project?

Comment: i don't use framelayout in this project also.

Comment: leaving office now, tell you whole story next day.

Comment: Thank you i will be waiting for your answer. and please write code lines according my sample. Thank you again.

Comment: Aditay where are you?

Answer (score 0):

As these two fragments use same activity,

to set value from First fragment :

```
            public void onClick(View v) {
            //what kind of code must be here ???
            //what kind of code must be here ???
            //what kind of code must be here ???
   getActivity().getIntent().putExtra("key", "value");
            }
```

To get value from second fragment :

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_second, container, false);
        //
 EditText et2 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et2);
String valueofet1 = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("key");
et2.setText(valueofet1 );
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: thank you but how can i get value and set to edittext i can not understand via this code.

Comment: check now @lotomax

Comment: i got an error on String valueofet1 = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("key"); //this line "E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                          at xmaxsoft.delfragment.Second.onCreateView(Second.java:28)"

Answer (score 0):

Replacing a fragment is better done from the activity.

In your First Fragment on btnShowSecond click listener inside onClick check if activity not null and if it is an instance of main activity and call method inside mainActivity that will switch fragments as so.

```
if(getActivity()!=null && getActivity instanceof MainActivity){
       ((MainActivity)getActivity()).showSecondFragment();
 }
```

And your showSecondFragment() method inside your MainActivity is as follows.

```
public void showSecondFragment(){
     getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.<the layout where you want to show second fragment>,new Second()).commit();
```

Please let me know if you have any doubts. Hope this helps.

A better way of doing it would be to use interface to call methods in activity from your fragment.

Have a look at the link below to learn about activity to fragment communication and vice versa.

https://laaptu.wordpress.com/tag/android-communication-between-fragment-and-activity/

Comment: Ragesh thank you for your answer but i can't to that. getSupportFragmentManager() is unknown. how can i use this methods according with my project?

Comment: just use getFragmentManager() instead. it should work fine

Comment: getFragmentManager() is ok but now your code doesn't work.

Comment: getActivity()  should be  an instance of whichever activity holds your fragment. getActivity instanceof <whichever activity holds the data> and ((<whichever activity holds the data>)getActivity()).showSecondFragment();

Comment: i don't understand completely. would you please tell me how can i write these lines on my project?

Comment: In which activity are you showing first and second fragment?

Comment: i want to show activity_second.xml in First.java (activity_first.xml) while button click.

Comment: replace(R.id.<the layout where you want to show second fragment> ... Here the layout represents the placeholder layout. What value are you giving here?

Comment: it doesn't work. because when i press R.id in android studio there is no intellisense layout suggestion...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;
btnShowSecond.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new second()).addToBackStack("second").commit();
            }
        });
```

on XML Add `FrameLayout`& i mentioned id-**containerView** hope it may helps

Comment: Ashwini thank you for your answer but i've tried your code but i can't to that. mFragmentTransaction ise unknow in my code.

Comment: @lotomax well i edited code..you have to declare FragmentTransaction.if this helps please Upvote

Comment: what can i replace with "R.id.containerView"?

Comment: check this https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html and i already mentioned you have to add FrameLayout on your XML page @lotomax

Comment: Ashwini sorry i am newbie on android and so please tell me how can i adapt this code to my project?

Comment: how can i add FrameLayout in my xml page?